# Selenium can't find element by class name which needs to be clicked

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On this page:

[image]

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL

I want to click the "Collapse All button"

Which are these classes:
[image]

I have tried this in a few different ways but it looks like selenium can't the button.
What can be the problem with mij code?

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL'
driver.get(url)
#   driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'expandPf Fz(s) Bd(0) C($linkColor) C($linkActiveColor):h Fw(500) D(n)--print Fl(end) Mt(5px)')#.click()
#   driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'expandPf Fz(s) Bd(0) C($linkColor) C($linkActiveColor):h Fw(500) D(n)--print Fl(end) Mt(5px)')#.click()
#   driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'expandPf Fz(s)')#.click()
    showmore_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'expandPf Fz(s) Bd(0) C($linkColor) C($linkActiveColor):h Fw(500) D(n)--print Fl(end) Mt(5px)')))
    showmore_link.click()
```

None of my options seem to work.

Comment: try replacing spaces with dots and precede with a dot so:".expandPf.Fz(s).Bd(0)......."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all these `expandPf` `Fz(s)` `Bd(0)` `C($linkColor)` `C($linkActiveColor):h` `Fw(500)` `D(n)--print` `Fl(end)` `Mt(5px)` are **multiple** and complex class names while `By.CLASS_NAME` receives **single** class name value. To work with multiple class name values you can use XPath or CSS Selectors.
But the easiest way to do that is to use XPath.
This XPath works: `//span[contains(text(),'Expand All')]`
This is the complete code I used. It expands the area after closing the pop-up

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Expand All')]"))).click()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works. I editted my inital post with an additional question to bypass the first screen. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I can help with that too, but. 1) Youd did not asked about that initially. 2) Each question should be about 1 specific issue 3) I need the link / flow to get that pop-up. So, please accept this answer since it resolves your initial question and please open a new, additional question for the second issue.

Comment: Thanks. However, using your initial input I must be able to solve that one myself!.
Thanks a lot for your help.